# How to display a Task Tile in sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to display a Task Title while running the workflow, which should
display and prompt following message "Do you want to delete" with Yes/No confirmation(something like Yes/No dialog-box)further to this user confirmation, the next workflow steps to be executed. For achiving this, in SharePoint designer how to do the workflow? and which "Action" to be used? can anyone please help me soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "Collect data from a user" Action in your workflow , you can create some column for getting data from user and after complete this task by user your workflow will go to next step , you can find more detail on [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/collect-data-from-a-user-in-a-workflow-HA010209808.aspx)